# Mapping from string to dynamic value with access failing

Tags: rust, hashmap

I'm rewritting some code for applying arguments to parameterized strings. It basically involves use of an argument list given as a `HashMap<String, Box<dyn Any>>`.

```
let map = applicable_string_map!{
    "a" => "foo",
    "b" => "bar",
};
```

This `applicable_string_map` macro wraps `"foo"` and `"bar"` into `Box<dyn Any>`. It returns a `HashMap<String, Box<dyn Any>>`.

The problem is that my asserts are failing to compile. It looks like I can't index the `HashMap` anymore:

```
use std::{any::Any, collections::HashMap};

fn main() {
    let map = HashMap::<String, Box<dyn Any>>::new();
    assert_eq!(
        *((&map[&"a".to_owned()]).downcast::<&'static str>().unwrap()),
        "foo"
    );
    assert_eq!(
        *map[&"b".to_owned()].downcast::<&'static str>().unwrap(),
        "bar"
    );
    assert!(map.get(&"c".to_owned()).is_none());
}
```

For simplification, instead of an assert I tried this:

```
let _v = map[&"a".to_owned()];
```

I get this VerifyError:

> cannot move out of index of `HashMap<String, Box<dyn Any>>`
> move occurs because value has type `Box<dyn Any>`, which does not implement the `Copy`
>
> consider borrowing here: `&map[&"a".to_owned()]`

So I did this at this line and it worked. But for the asserts, still not.

I tried a lot of things.

Comment: You should really try to provide a [mre] such as [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cc8c711102c5f679edb25241afa72a26) when asking. Especially all that commented out code does *not* need to be here.

Comment: @cafce25 I've improved it a little.

Comment: I don't mean a playground link, but more it's contents, a short, complete example that produces the error without any unnecessary bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`Any::downcast_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast_ref) instead of [`Any::downcast`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast) to avoid moving out of the value of your hashmap entry:

```rust
#[test]
fn string_application() {
    let map = applicable_string_map!{
        "a" => "foo",
        "b" => "bar",
    };
    
    let _v: &Box<dyn Any> = &map["a"];
    
    assert_eq!(
        *map["a"].downcast_ref::<&'static str>().unwrap(),
        "foo"
    );
    
    assert_eq!(
        *map["b"].downcast_ref::<&'static str>().unwrap(),
        "bar"
    );
    
    assert!(map.get(&"c".to_owned()).is_none());
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b81500f10d37eafd648863607c831331)